# ActiveRecord: validates_associated does not work when updating model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 2 models:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :book_versions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :book_versions, allow_destroy: true
  validates_associated :book_versions

class BookVersion < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collection_items
  has_many :collections, through: :collection_items
  belongs_to :book
  validates_presence_of :price, :isbn #<-- validates presence
```

Everything works fine and dandy when I go to books/new and create a book with multiple book versions. The validations fire when I leave the price or isbn blank.

However, after I create a book with multiple book versions and I go back to the edit form and I delete one of the prices of an existing associated book_version and I submit the book form, it "updates successfully the book successfully". There are 2 problems here:

1. The `validates_presence_of :price` is not fired
2. The book version doesn't actually update.

Here's a copy of part of the params:

> "book_versions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"alt", "isbn"=>"",
>   "price"=>"", "famis_number"=>"", "famis_price"=>"",
>   "weight_in_pounds"=>""}, "1"=>{"name"=>"bb",
>   "isbn"=>"123123123123222222", "price"=>"", "famis_number"=>"",
>   "famis_price"=>"", "weight_in_pounds"=>"1.0", "inventory"=>"08",
>   "id"=>"1030"}, ...

Everything supposedly "saves", but when I check the database, the `bb` book_version still has the old price.

Why is it failing silently and why aren't my validations firing?

Comment: i think validates_associated should be on :book not :book_version bcoz your BookVersion belongs to Book, so your BookVersion have book_id and you should write validates_associated :book inside BookVersion

Comment: but this line will only validate whether the parent means Book in this case is present or not.

Comment: sorry for my comment, after reading this http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated it seems i m wrong, and your code is correct.

Comment: Hey @RahulSingh . Looks like it's a Rails bug. I figured it out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634107/rails-accepts-nested-attributes-for-is-not-updating-my-has-many-association